# Lock Services techniques for scriptDB writing

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am looking to implement Lock Services on my script to prevent database collisions, but all of the examples seem geared towards multiples triggers of the same block of code. My triggers are all for different functions which do different writes to the ScriptDB, but the information written can sometimes conflict.

I'm having trouble visualizing how Lock Services would be used in this case, since at the moment none of the code blocks being executed overlap. Should I have one central keyMaster() function that all of my existing functions check with before doing a db.save()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the system I've put together. This simple test works as expected, but it is harder to test in my full script where edge cases I'm not aware of might not exist.

Any comments on this?

```
      function keyMaster(type, myLock) {
      //call with following to create a lock
      //var lock = keyMaster("lock"); // Check that response is not null
      //Call with the following to release
      //lock = keyMaster("unlock", lock);  
        if (type === "lock") {
          try {
            var lock = LockService.getPublicLock();
            lock.waitLock(45000);
            return lock;
          }
          catch(e) {
            Logger.log ("Keymaster error\n" + e.message);
            return null;
          }
        }
        else {
            myLock.releaseLock();
            return myLock;
        }
      }


      function block1() {

        var lock = keyMaster("lock");
        if (lock) {
          Utilities.sleep(10000);
          lock = keyMaster("unlock", lock);  
        }

      }


      function block2() {

        var lock = keyMaster("lock");
        if (lock) {
          Utilities.sleep(0);
          lock = keyMaster("unlock", lock);  
          return "block2 locked and unlocked";
        }
        else {
          return "block2 could not get lock";
        }  
      }
```